# Why do I see odd behavior of subscript on scalars?

Tags: list, indexing, range, raku, scalar

It appears as if a scalar by itself is sort of a list of one item:

```
> "foo"[1]
Index out of range. Is: 1, should be in 0..0
  in block <unit> at <unknown file> line 5

> "foo"[0]
foo
> "foo"[*-1]
foo
```

I say sort of a list of one because lists don't seem to have a range on their indexes:

```
> (0, 1, 2)[3]
Nil
```

What is going on here.  What am I not understanding about the `[]` operator.

Comment: Shouldn't you rather look at  (0, 1, 2)[2] as there is no third element of that list?

Comment: @BarneySchmale I am demonstrating the difference in the out of range behavior between the sort-of-list-of-one nature of scalars (dies) and actual lists (returns `Nil`), so no.

Comment: The `[]` operator is explained in depth [here](https://docs.perl6.org/language/subscripts.html). It is designed ti be very generic and reusable - what happens in case of non-existent elements, is up to the object you're indexing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a feature of `Any`. From [the docs](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Any):

> Since Perl 6 intentionally confuses items and single-element lists, most methods in `Any` are also present on class `List`, and coerce to `List` or a list-like type.

If you [look at the implementation](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/34f9508/src/core/Any.pm#L255), you'll see that there is no actual coercion necessary as `Any` provides `AT-POS`, and that's what fails for indices different from 0.

In contrast, the [implementation of actual lists](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/7e35062/src/core/List.pm#L559) only fails in case of negative indices and returns `Nil` otherwise.

Semantically, this is not entirely insane as one way to think of `Nil` is as a quiet failure, but it is indeed an inconsistency. It  *might* be by design, as the 'listiness' of items is just a convenience feature and not part of the interface proper and thus might be supposed to complain noisily if misused.

Note that `Array` gives a third behaviour by returning `Any` by default, which can be understood in the context of auto-vivification.

Comment: Apparently, the thought process is that you can use the return from a function as a list and it just works (eg `"foo".elems` returns 1).  It looks like a better error message is being mooted on the #perl6 IRC channel.

Answer (score 5):

> It appears as if a scalar by itself is sort of a list of one item

If you explicitly apply a list operation to a scalar it behaves as if it were a list containing one element which is that scalar value.

> What am I not understanding about the [] operator.

Indexing operations on a list (any [Positional](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Positional) data structure; a List is a list but a list may not be a List) are checked according to the list's "shape", a list of "Indexing ranges".

You can only explicitly declare the indexing ranges of an Array.

```
# Value treated as list    shape   Indexing range

'a scalar value'           (1)     0..0         
(0,1,2)                    (*)     0..Inf
my @a                      (*)     0..Inf
my @b[42]                  (42)    0..41
```

---

(I'm slightly surprised by Lists (eg `(0,1,2)`), which have immutable shape, being assigned a shape of `(*)`. Why not `(3)` (in the case of a 3 element list) if this is both known and immutable? (Perhaps it isn't?))